# SQL phpMyAdmin- cannot find foreign key constrain

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

After I create table Artist and table Album on phpMyAdmin, when I try to create table Track, I keep getting error- **#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint**. Can it be from NULL?

```
CREATE TABLE Artist (
artist_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(artist_id)
)

CREATE TABLE Album (
album_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(255),
artist_id INTEGER,

PRIMARY KEY(album_id),
INDEX USING BTREE (title),

CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (artist_id)
REFERENCES Artist (artist_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;



CREATE TABLE Track (  <--ERROR STARTS AFTER I TRY TO CREATE TRACK.
track_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title VARCHAR(255),
len INTEGER,
rating INTEGER,
count INTEGER,
album_id INTEGER,
genre_id INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY(track_id),
INDEX USING BTREE (title),

CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (album_id) REFERENCES Album (album_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Album (genre_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Album (genre_id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE------------ Error is in this.. "genre_id" is not a column of "Album" table.

Comment: One more thing, you can create reference your key with another table's primary key only

Comment: Mittal wow thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with below statement

```
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Album (genre_id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

`genre_id` is not a column of the `Album` table.

> Moreover, foreign key will be created with another table's primary key only...